# Completely exclude checkbox element from form?

Tags: html

How can I completely exclude an input (specifically, a checkbox) from a form? Specifically, how to keep it from resetting when the form is reset. There are numerous answers for how to prevent it from being submitted with a form, however none seem to address the issue of form resets.

My problem is that I need to place a checkbox on my page for user control of an option, but it needs to be located in the middle of a bunch of form inputs. Since it is only a user option selection box, and not part of the form, however, I need it to be excluded from all form operations, such as resetting the form or submitting the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have to do this kind of form reset by using Javascript.

Here is the fiddle example

http://jsfiddle.net/8K7Bt/

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {
    $("form").on('reset', function() {
        var inputs = $(this).find(":checkbox");
        inputs.each(function() {
            $(this).data('value', $(this).is(':checked'));
        });
        this.reset();
        inputs.each(function() {
            $(this).attr('checked', $(this).data('value'));
        });
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <input type="text" />
    <br/>
    <select>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <label><input type="radio" name="radio" /> radio 1</label><br/>
    <label><input type="radio" name="radio" /> radio 2</label>
    <br/>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" checked='checked' /> checkbox 1 (excluded from reset)</label><br/>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" /> checkbox 2 (excluded from reset)</label>
        <br/>
        <br/>
    <input type="reset" value="reset me" />
</form>
```

Comment: I actually prefer the answer by qiu-deqing, but being HTML5 and not supported in XP IE, I can't quite use it yet. Maybe next year.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to adapt this to keep whichever radio input had been selected, but reset the rest.. Thanks again!

Answer (score 7):

if you are working with modern browsers that support html5 you can use form attribute of

as mdn describes:

**The form element that the input element is associated with (its form owner). The value of the attribute must be an id of a  element in the same document. If this attribute is not specified, this  element must be a descendant of a  element. This attribute enables you to place  elements anywhere within a document, not just as descendants of their form elements. An input can only be associated with one form.**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input

so you can simple set form attribute to a dummy id which did not exist in the document

this can simple exclude the input from its containing form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zh">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>html5 template .html</title>

  </head>

  <body>
    <form>
      <input type="checkbox" name="hello"/>aaa
      <input type="checkbox" name="hello"/>bbb
      <input type="checkbox" name="option" form="dummy"/>ccc
      <input type="submit"/>
      <input type="reset"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

in the code above. when you click reset. option is not reset

when you click submit option is not submit(see address after click submit, something like: ?hello=on&hello=on)

Comment: I actually prefer this answer in general, however the form HTML5 attribute is still not supported on some browsers my company has to support.